# No such column in Drizzle JDBC

Tags: mysql-connector, drizzle

Now Iam using Drizzle `drizzle-jdbc-1.1` instead of `mysql-connector-java-5.1.12`. But when reading data from my table, it shows an error like this. But this issue is present only when using `drizzle-jdbc` and the query successfully works with `mysql-jdbc`. Why?

```
SQLException information
Error msg: No such column: sampletable.DataUpdated
SQLSTATE: null
Error code: 0
java.sql.SQLException: No such column: sampletable.DataUpdated
    at org.drizzle.jdbc.internal.SQLExceptionMapper.getSQLException(SQLExceptionMapper.java:116)
    at org.drizzle.jdbc.DrizzleResultSet.getValueObject(DrizzleResultSet.java:145)
    at org.drizzle.jdbc.DrizzleResultSet.getLong(DrizzleResultSet.java:164)
    at com.samples.service.TestService.fetchData(TestService.java:327)
    at com.samples.views.TestDataView$3.run(TestDataView.java:401)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:54)
Caused by: org.drizzle.jdbc.internal.common.queryresults.NoSuchColumnException: No such column: sampletable.DataUpdated
    at org.drizzle.jdbc.internal.common.queryresults.DrizzleQueryResult.getValueObject(DrizzleQueryResult.java:97)
    at org.drizzle.jdbc.DrizzleResultSet.getValueObject(DrizzleResultSet.java:143)
    ... 4 more
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(drizzle-jdbc author here)

You should try the latest snapshot version of drizzle-jdbc, there was a bug where you couldnt use <database>.<table> before: https://github.com/krummas/DrizzleJDBC/issues/6

latest is available here:
https://repository.sonatype.org/service/local/artifact/maven/redirect?r=ossrh-snapshot&g=org.drizzle.jdbc&a=drizzle-jdbc&v=1.2-SNAPSHOT&e=jar

Ill soon build 1.2, which contains this and more fixes.

Comment: The mentioned issue is now fixed. But now I face anotehr one issue, that is some rows have data '0' only from my java application. But same query is properly return the coorect answer.

Comment: could you report a bug on github?